# ckeditor - Two views with editable fields on the same page

Tags: views, wysiwyg

I have put two identical pane views (an original display along with a clone)  on the same page. I needed two copies because each view has its own set of exposed filters, so they can display different nodes side-by-side.

The views consist of multiple [editable fields](https://www.drupal.org/project/editablefields) that seem to be identical comparing to the other view so they have even the same element IDs..

As a result, ckeditor which is the default wysiwyg editor only loads on the first view, giving me the following error on console:

```
Uncaught The editor instance "edit-field-e1-0-field-e1-und-0-value" is already attached to the provided element. ckeditor.js?o5iwm7:286
```

How can I prevent this? Is there a way to set different ids on cloned displays?

If I recreate the same display manually, would it be any difference? (its a huge display)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To counter this, I had to clone every field in the second display only to force Drupal to assign different element IDs to each one. Then I deleted the initial fields.

So

```
views-field views-field-field-e1
```

changed to

```
views-field views-field-field-e1-1
```

letting the Ckeditor to render the rich text editor on every instance.